# Поиск аномалий с помощью scikit-learn на python

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Какие алгоритмы возможно использовать для поиска аномалий с помощью `skit-learn python` кроме `OneClassSVM`?

Существует ли способ привести другие алгоритмы к одноклассовым?

Например, используя `weka` можно использовать `One class classifer` и с помощью него использовать любой алгоритм для поиска аномалий. Существует ли аналогичный способ в `scikit-learn`

Первоначально задача состоит в том, чтобы сравнить эффективность различных алгоритмов машинного обучения для поиска аномалий на выбранных данных.

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/covariance/plot_outlier_detection.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-covariance-plot-outlier-detection-py

Comment: Есть еще Isolation Forest http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html